# Need to change [product_categories] Woocommerce shortcode thumbnail size

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, hook-woocommerce

In a site with Aurum Theme (Laborator) I use [product_categories] Woocommerce shortcode for display a grid of sub-categories of a parent.

I set the size of thumbnails in "Appearance" > "Customize" > "Woocommerce" > "Product images".
Different posts say that set this size affects both product thumbnails and categories thumbnails, but when I change this value nothing happens on the page with the shortcode.

Where can I change the values only for categories of thumbnails sizes?
I would like to set 1:1 size for all thumbnails.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to regenerate your thumbnails in order to see it work Eleonora.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return array(
        'width'  => 150,
        'height' => 150,
        'crop'   => 1,
    );
} );
```

Try adding this to your active theme `functions.php` file

Comment: Hi mujuonly, 
thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me, I'll go on trying to solve it. Have a good day, bye!